# How to get value using key in python multi dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
{
 "card_quota": 0,
 "custom_data": "{\"child_name\":\"홍설\",\"uid\":\"29\",\"lid\":\"56\",\"count\":\"1\",\"schedule\":\"2016-06-18(토)\"}",
 "escrow": false
}
```

This is dictionary type of python. I konw to get value using a code like temp['card_quata']. But i want to know using key in ['custom_data'] getting value like child_name or uid .. How can i do that?

Comment: You'll get `NameError` if you use `false` instead of `False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse `custom_data` with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) and then access the returned `dict`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(temp['custom_data'])['child_name']
'홍설'
```

Note that the example data you provided is not valid Python since Python uses `False` instead of `false`.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. Sorry but I don't know why json.loads method doesn't work when i write json.loads(temp)???

Comment: @LeeJinHee In the given example `temp` is a dictionary, not a string. `loads` takes in `str` (or `unicode`) and deserializes it.

Comment: oh! really appreciate

Answer (score -1):

You can simply get the values of any dictionary using the keys. So lets take it step by step:
first, lets get the dictionary -

```
temp['custom_data']
```

will give you the child dictionary, then, in order to access the items of this child dict, you can use the child keys:

```
temp['custom_data']['child_name']
temp['custom_data']['uid']
```

etc.

Comment: You forgot to point out that its a json and prior to accessing its keys, you had to json.loads() on it

Comment: thanks. But custom_data value is not dict type so it doesn't work. Value type is str. Therefore i think value in custom_data have to convert dict type.

Comment: Yes, and therefore @niemmi answer should work for you